# What is the object owner referred to in the Google C++ Style Guide?

Tags: c++

The [Google Style Guide for C++](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Smart_Pointers) says, in the section about smart pointers:

- We prefer designs in which objects have single, fixed owners.

I don't fully understand the sentence.

- What is the object owner?
- Is it just the pointer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'owner' of an object is not an actual part of the C++ language, but rather a conceptual tool - the idea being the 'owner' is in charge of deciding when the object can be destroyed. If an object has a single owner, it's easy to figure out when the object needs to be destroyed - just look at the owner. When an object is referenced by multiple other objects, however, things are less clear - none of the referring objects can, on its own, delete the referee object, as this would cause problems for the other referers. So there there is no "single, fixed owner".

To give some examples, consider a 'picture' object.

```
class Picture {
  char *rawData;
public:
  Picture(char *rawData_) : rawData(rawData_) { }
  Picture(const Picture &p) : rawData(p.rawData) { }
};
```

Picture does *not* own `rawData`; as we can see from the copy constructor, it's all too easy to have multiple Pictures referencing the same data. A better version might look like:

```
class Picture {
  std::vector<char> rawData;
public:
  Picture(const std::vector<char> &rawData_) : rawData(rawData_) { }
};
```

This is similar, but now vector is hiding the raw pointer for us; it's impossible to have two `Pictures` reference the same pointer. And we take care of destroying the rawData array when the Picture is destroyed. In this case, the Picture owns the raw data.

Now, you don't *have* to use STL containers to have an owned object. You could do it manually:

```
class Picture {
  size_t rawDataSize;
  char *rawData;

public:
  Picture(size_t rds, char *rd) {
    rawDataSize = rds;
    rawData = new char[rds];
    memcpy(rawData, rd, rds);
  }

  ~Picture() { delete [] rawData; }

  Picture(const Picture &pic) {
    rawDataSize = pic.rawDataSize;
    rawData = new char[rawDataSize];
    memcpy(rawData, pic.rawData, rawDataSize);
  }

  Picture& operator=(const Picture &pic) {
    delete [] rawData;
    rawDataSize = pic.rawDataSize;
    rawData = new char[rawDataSize];
    memcpy(rawData, pic.rawData, rawDataSize);
    return *this;
  }
};
```

This is also an owning relationship; the rawData array 'belongs' to the picture object, permanently. All accesses go through the picture object, and it's destroyed along with the picture object.

In general, with owning relationships, it's recommended to use wrapper classes to automate destruction, and prevent accidental copying. In my third example, had I forgotten the copy constructor or `operator=`, for example, terrible things would happen. Using wrapper classes like `std::unique_ptr`, `boost::scoped_ptr`/`boost::scoped_array`, or `std::vector` (for owned arrays) help prevent you from making mistakes.

Comment: Ok, 'owner' is not actual part of the C++ language. In c++, however, how it is implemented. Is it just pointer to the object?

Comment: @capoluca, 'owner' is a concept, so there's any number of ways to implement an ownership relationship. A pointer might be part of ownership, but then again a pointer can point to a shared (non-owned) object as well.

Comment: @bdonlan what happens when we don't need/want copy semantics and/or copy is expensive? Do we just pass everything as a shared_ptr?

Answer (score 2):

Following bdonlan's answer, a C++ example:

```
int main()
{
    // owner of 'obj' is main()
    Object *obj = new Object;

    // even if 'foo' receives an object, it is not its owner;
    // it shouldn't be responsible for destroying it
    foo(obj);

    // obj is still alive
    obj->DoSomething();

    // the owner should clean up what it created
    delete obj;
}
```

You asked,

> In c++, how it is implemented. Is it just pointer to the object?

Often it will be a pointer but not always. As bdonlan said, ownership is a concept that the owner of an object will be in charge of cleaning up afterwards. An example with reference:

```
void foo(Object &obj) {}

int main()
{
    // owner of 'obj' is main()
    Object obj;
    obj.Init();

    foo(obj);

    // the owner is responsible for calling Cleanup()
    // it would be unnatural and confusing if Cleanup() 
    // was called in foo(), which is not the owner
    obj.Cleanup();
}
```